# Table with html and ajax paginate

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, pagination

I've got this table that has an ajax call populating it as well as some rails.

I'm wondering how i can paginate it?

It looks like this at the moment.

```
  <% if @gmiresults.present?%>
  <% @gmiresults.each do |gmi| %>

  <tr style="font-weight:bold">
    <td>
      <%= image_tag("getmein-logo.png", style: "width: 140px") %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= gmi.product_name%>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= gmi.stock_quantity%>
    </td>
    <td>
      £<%= gmi.search_price %>
    </td>
    <td>
      N/A
    </td>
    <td>
      £<%= gmi.search_price %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= link_to "Buy Now", gmi.aw_deep_link, class: "btn btn-info" %>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

And in the ajax call

```
  "<a class='btn btn-info' data-url='"+ url +"'>Buy Now</a>";
        $("#tabledirect").append("<tr><td><img id='theImg' src='/assets/logo.png'/></td><td><b>" + section +
        "</b></td><td><b> In Stock </b></td><td><b>£" + price + "</b></td><td><b>N/A</b></td><td><b>£" + price +"</b></td><td><b>" + button + "</b></td></tr>");
        $("#tabledirect").find(".btn.btn-info").click(function() {
          location.href = $(this).attr("data-url");
        });
```

I've tried looking at the kaminari gem but it kinda went over my head.

Thanks

Comment: you can try to use https://www.datatables.net/ it has a lot of nice features and easy to use.Gem for it https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails

Comment: do a row count of the items you want to display (total), then divide by the amount of items per page you want to display (per page), then make buttons per page, then add event listener to the buttons which will call an ajax function to refresh the contents of the table by calling a php script and setting `$('table').html(AjaxResponse)`

Comment: @FMashiro I can't use a php script? I'm using rails?

Comment: @SamRoberts Then you should store all the results in a json format in a hidden input field on the page, and using JS you can select from position x to position y and put the new data back in the table I guess?